# Converting ctype float to python float properly

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, precision, ctypes

I am receiving a `ctype` `c_float` via a C library that I would like to convert to a regular python `float`.

The problem is that `ctype` uses 32 bit precision while python uses 64 bit precision.

Say a user enters the number `1.9` into the C user interface. The number is represented as `1.899999976158142`. When I print it on the C side, this representation is taken into account and I get an output of `1.9`.

However on the python side, when I convert the `c_float` to python with its higher precision, then the number will not be treated as a `1.9` when printing, but as `1.899999976158142` instead.

How do I solve this?

I found a way, but it's a bit clunky (and unnecessarily inefficient), so I was hoping for a more elegant solution:

```py
float_c = ctypes.c_float(1.9)  # c_float(1.899999976158142)

float_32 = float_c.value  # 1.899999976158142
float_str = f"{float_32:g}"  # "1.9"
float_py = float(float_str)  # 1.9
```

Since the precision will only become a problem during conversion to string (printing and writing to file), I could just live with it and omit the last step, but I find it inelegant to keep the number in its "problematic" state where I have to worry about the conversion every time I may want to print it.

Instead I think it's cleaner to just convert it once at the handover point between the C lib and python and never worry about it again.

So should I just do the conversion from `c_float` to python float like this or is there a better way?

Comment: Cerno, "How do I solve this?" Nothing to really solve.  Say a user enters the number `1.89999997615814208984375` into the C user interface - a value _exactly_ encodable as a 32-bit floating point, would you want `1.899999976158142`, `1.9`, `1.89999997615814208984375` or what on the output?  I recommend to simply print 7 _significant_ digits in exponential format or 1.900000e+0.

Comment: This is a corner case I am willing to ignore, as the user inputs are known to have a reasonable number of digits. I would treat your example pretty much like C++ does when printing floats. Apparently they make some assumption about readability as well in that regard. Compare `cout << 1.899999;` and `cout << 1.89999;` One rounds to `1.9`, the other does not.

Comment: About printing 7 significant digits: Is that your arbitrary choice or is that some consensus value? I was thinking about just rounding at some digit, but I didn't just want to pull any value out of my hat if there is a way that's somewhat agreed on. That's why I chose to do the `g` conversion, as that's at least a format that has some consensus in the way it behaves. I just wish I could do it without the clumsy string conversion.

Comment: This raises an interesting question though: What is a "correct" conversion from float32 to float64? Since a float32 representation of the "real world" precise float is inherently inaccurate, how should we convert to float64? If the precise value was `1.9`, then converting to `1.899999976158142` in float64 would be inaccurate. If the precise value was `1.899999976158142`, then converting to `1.9` would be equally inaccurate. It's impossible to solve in general. Fortunately, in my case I know that the C++ user input is limited to a certain number of digits, so I know that `1.9` must be correct.

Comment: Not arbitrary.  For [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), 7 is the number of _significant_ decimal places to read and print the same.  9 is the number of _significant_ decimal to print all values distinctively.

Comment: "If the original value was 1.9" is amiss.  _Code_ or user input might have been _text_ `"1.9"`, but the saved float32 is 1.89999997615814208984375, not 1.9.  All float32 converted to float64 retain the same exact value.  All float32, float64 are some integer times a power of 2.  1.9 is not in those sets.

Comment: Yes, I rephrased it from "original" to "precise". What I meant is the value that the user enters. I know that both numbers are exactly the same in float32 and without a priori knowledge we cannot know whether the conversion to float64 represents the intended value or not. But if we have the a priori knowledge, we can actually do that. If the user input was `1.9` and I know that it could not have more than let's say 10 digits, I can make use of that information to make the conversion to float64 more precise.

Comment: Cerno, Suggest that instead of passing only the float32, also pass meta info like its significant decimal length (2).  A good alternative is to simply pass a _string_ `"1.9"`.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be the best case if I absolutely need to get a perfectly reusable solution. In my specific case it would probably be enough to assume that anything more than 6-8 digits is likely not what the user intended and transform it similar to what I did or @anis-r suggested. It seems like this problem is much more complicated than I initially thought. I thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have pointed out that the number converted to float64 from float32 is *exactly* the same value stored in C and you need knowledge of the original number to meet your definition of more precise, but you can round the resulting number to the same number of decimal places as C (or what you think the user intended) and the resulting float64 will be closer to that value:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> x=struct.unpack('f',struct.pack('f',1.9))[0] # trick to achieve converted number
>>> x
1.899999976158142
>>> y=round(x,7)  # or to whatever places you expect the user to enter
>>> y
1.9
>>> format(x,'.20f')
'1.89999997615814208984'
>>> format(y,'.20f')
'1.89999999999999991118'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing after all discussion here. Since there seems to be no consensus about the number of digits to round to (see my comment under @anis-r's post about the difference between `cout` and `numpy`), I simply decided on a sensible value and now my solution is `round(value, 6)`

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround is to use numpy's `float32`:

```
>>> float_c = ctypes.c_float(1.9)
>>> np.float32(float_c)
1.9
```

Comment: That's a good one, thanks! I'll accept it if nobody can come up with a native way to do it.

Comment: Interestingly, both versions produce slightly different results. My version is in line with the cut off point c++ uses when printing: `cout << 1.89999` produces `1.89999`, while `cout << 1.899999` produces `1.9`. For numpy it's a bit different: `np.float32(1.8999999)` produces `1.8999999`, while `np.float32(1.89999997)` produces `1.9`, so it needs 2 digits more to round the number